# Hypothetical question: Can you embed flash in java JFrames?

Tags: java, plugins, flash

JFrames or Java in general do they have some sort of flash plugin extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As for Swing, I do not think so. But it should be possible with AWT - please find [this link](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/ocx/Sysinfo_OCX.html), that should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which plays Flash via the Internet Explorer OCX plug-in, and can even capture screenshots from the Flash object. It needs SWT however.

Edit: Actually, not really. It looks like it does the SWT image conversion later. You can use the BufferedImage with a JComponent or something, just by drawing it.

```
/**
 * 
 */
package swfexp1;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.DirectColorModel;
import java.awt.image.IndexColorModel;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.PaletteData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.RGB;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleAutomation;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleFrame;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.Variant;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

import swfexp1.res.ResRoot;

public final class SWFExp1 {
    private GC canvas, snapGC;
    private Canvas snapCanvas;
    private Shell shell;
    private OleFrame frame;
    //private OleControlSite oleCSite;
    private OleClientSite oleClSite;
    private OleAutomation oleAuto;
    private Display display;
    private long lastSnapshotMS = System.currentTimeMillis();
    private long lastUpdateTimeMS = System.currentTimeMillis();

    private Composite viewComp;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public SWFExp1() {
        display = Display.getDefault();
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(1050, 550);

        GridLayout l = new GridLayout(2, false);
        shell.setLayout(l);

        canvas = new GC(shell);
        frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);

        GridData d = new GridData();
        frame.setLayoutData(d);

        d = new GridData();
        viewComp = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        viewComp.setLayoutData(d);
        //viewComp.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);

        snapCanvas = new Canvas(viewComp, SWT.NONE);
        d = new GridData(500, 500);
        snapCanvas.setLayoutData(d);
        snapCanvas.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        snapGC = new GC(snapCanvas);

        //oleCSite = new OleControlSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash");
        oleClSite = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash");
        System.out.println("oleclsite: " + oleClSite);

        oleClSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);
        oleClSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_SHOW);

        oleClSite.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        oleAuto = new OleAutomation(oleClSite);

        shell.setVisible(true);
        shell.open();

        int[] rgdispid = oleAuto.getIDsOfNames(new String[]{"Play"}); 
        int playID = rgdispid[0];
        System.out.println("playID: " + playID);

        rgdispid = oleAuto.getIDsOfNames(new String[]{"Movie"}); 
        int moviePropSetID = rgdispid[0];
        System.out.println("moviePropSetID: " + moviePropSetID);        

        rgdispid = oleAuto.getIDsOfNames(new String[]{"Stop"}); 
        int stopID = rgdispid[0];
        System.out.println("stopID: " + stopID);

        rgdispid = oleAuto.getIDsOfNames(new String[]{"Back"}); 
        int backID = rgdispid[0];
        System.out.println("backID: " + backID);

        rgdispid = oleAuto.getIDsOfNames(new String[]{"Forward"}); 
        int forwardID = rgdispid[0];
        System.out.println("forwardID: " + forwardID);

        rgdispid = oleAuto.getIDsOfNames(new String[]{"StopPlay"}); 
        int stopPlayID = rgdispid[0];
        System.out.println("stopPlayID: " + stopPlayID);

        rgdispid = oleAuto.getIDsOfNames(new String[]{"LoadMovie", "layer", "url"}); 
        int loadMovieID = rgdispid[0];
        System.out.println("loadMovieID: " + loadMovieID);

        Variant[] rgvarg = new Variant[2];
        //String fileName = "file:///C:/Users/Public/blah/cubes.swf";
        ResRoot r = new ResRoot();
        String fileName =  r.getClass().getResource("runanim.swf").toString();
        fileName = fileName.replace("file:/", "file://");

        System.out.println("fname: " + fileName);
        rgvarg[0] = new Variant(0); // layer
        rgvarg[1] = new Variant(fileName); // path

        //Variant[] rgvarg2 = new Variant[1];
        //String fileName2 = "C:\\Users\\Public\\blah\\cubes.swf";
        //rgvarg2[0] = new Variant(fileName2);
        //boolean done = oleAuto.setProperty(moviePropSetID, rgvarg[0]);

        //System.out.println("done: " + done);

        Variant pVarResult1 = oleAuto.invoke(loadMovieID, rgvarg);
        Variant pVarResult2 = oleAuto.invoke(playID);

        System.out.println("pvarr1: " + pVarResult1);
        //System.out.println("pvarr2: " + pVarResult2);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
            lastUpdateTimeMS = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (lastUpdateTimeMS >= (lastSnapshotMS + 300)) {
                takeSnap();
                lastSnapshotMS = lastUpdateTimeMS;
            }
        }
        oleAuto.dispose();
        display.dispose();
    }

    /**
     * Take snapshot and put it in the view
     */
    private void takeSnap() {
        System.out.println("cheese!");
        Image i = new Image(canvas.getDevice(), 500, 500);
        canvas.copyArea(i, 0, 0);
        snapGC.drawImage(i, 0, 0);

        //canvas.copyArea(snapCanvas.get, );
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SWFExp1 exp1 = new SWFExp1();
        exp1.run();
    }

    public static final BufferedImage convertToAWT(ImageData data) {
        ColorModel colorModel = null;
        PaletteData palette = data.palette;
        if (palette.isDirect) {
            colorModel = new DirectColorModel(data.depth, palette.redMask, palette.greenMask, palette.blueMask);
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(colorModel, colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(data.width, data.height), false, null);
            WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
            int[] pixelArray = new int[3];
            for (int y = 0; y < data.height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < data.width; x++) {
                    int pixel = data.getPixel(x, y);
                    RGB rgb = palette.getRGB(pixel);
                    pixelArray[0] = rgb.red;
                    pixelArray[1] = rgb.green;
                    pixelArray[2] = rgb.blue;
                    raster.setPixels(x, y, 1, 1, pixelArray);
                }
            }
            return bufferedImage;
        }

        // otherwise...     
        RGB[] rgbs = palette.getRGBs();
        byte[] red = new byte[rgbs.length];
        byte[] green = new byte[rgbs.length];
        byte[] blue = new byte[rgbs.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < rgbs.length; i++) {
            RGB rgb = rgbs[i];
            red[i] = (byte) rgb.red;
            green[i] = (byte) rgb.green;
            blue[i] = (byte) rgb.blue;
        }
        if (data.transparentPixel != -1) {
            colorModel = new IndexColorModel(data.depth, rgbs.length, red, green, blue, data.transparentPixel);
        } else {
            colorModel = new IndexColorModel(data.depth, rgbs.length, red, green, blue);
        }
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(colorModel, colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(data.width, data.height), false, null);
        WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
        int[] pixelArray = new int[1];
        for (int y = 0; y < data.height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < data.width; x++) {
                int pixel = data.getPixel(x, y);
                pixelArray[0] = pixel;
                raster.setPixel(x, y, pixelArray);
            }
        }
        return bufferedImage;
    }

    static ImageData convertToSWT(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
        if (bufferedImage.getColorModel() instanceof DirectColorModel) {
            DirectColorModel colorModel = (DirectColorModel) bufferedImage.getColorModel();
            PaletteData palette = new PaletteData(colorModel.getRedMask(), colorModel.getGreenMask(), colorModel.getBlueMask());
            ImageData data = new ImageData(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), colorModel.getPixelSize(), palette);
            WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
            int[] pixelArray = new int[3];
            for (int y = 0; y < data.height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < data.width; x++) {
                    raster.getPixel(x, y, pixelArray);
                    int pixel = palette.getPixel(new RGB(pixelArray[0], pixelArray[1], pixelArray[2]));
                    data.setPixel(x, y, pixel);
                }
            }
            return data;
        } else if (bufferedImage.getColorModel() instanceof IndexColorModel) {
            IndexColorModel colorModel = (IndexColorModel) bufferedImage.getColorModel();
            int size = colorModel.getMapSize();
            byte[] reds = new byte[size];
            byte[] greens = new byte[size];
            byte[] blues = new byte[size];
            colorModel.getReds(reds);
            colorModel.getGreens(greens);
            colorModel.getBlues(blues);
            RGB[] rgbs = new RGB[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < rgbs.length; i++) {
                rgbs[i] = new RGB(reds[i] & 0xFF, greens[i] & 0xFF, blues[i] & 0xFF);
            }
            PaletteData palette = new PaletteData(rgbs);
            ImageData data = new ImageData(bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), colorModel.getPixelSize(), palette);
            data.transparentPixel = colorModel.getTransparentPixel();
            WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
            int[] pixelArray = new int[1];
            for (int y = 0; y < data.height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < data.width; x++) {
                    raster.getPixel(x, y, pixelArray);
                    data.setPixel(x, y, pixelArray[0]);
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static final ImageData createSampleImage(Display display) {
        Image image = new Image(display, 100, 100);
        Rectangle bounds = image.getBounds();
        GC gc = new GC(image);
        gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
        gc.fillRectangle(bounds);
        gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));
        gc.fillOval(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height);
        gc.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
        gc.drawLine(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height);
        gc.drawLine(bounds.width, 0, 0, bounds.height);
        gc.dispose();
        ImageData data = image.getImageData();
        image.dispose();
        return data;
    }

}
```